# Derivation of stability criterion for type 3 digital PLL

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, stability, pll

Could anyone help to derive the following expression (4.23) which is the stability criterion for type 3 digital PLL ?

Note: Screenshots are taken from Floyd Gardner's book : Phaselock Techniques 3rd Edition

[image]

[image]